# Building a 64-bit application with Qt

Tags: qt, 64-bit

I have only been using Qt (version 4.8) for about a week, and it is working like a charm. So far I have only built 32-bit applications with Qt creator, however I would like to build my application as a 64-bit application because it handles large data sets and requires lots of RAM. Can someone please tell me what are the steps involved to build a project from Qt creator as a 64-bit application ? Please note that my OS is Widows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, i also have Visual Studio 2010 Pro on the same machine. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Start Menu (MSVS2010 - VS Tools) start the "Visual Studio x64 Win64 Command Prompt" and then compile from the command line. It worked for me without problems but it takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Qt supply a 64bit build but it's easy to do your own

Just fire up the visual studio 64bit tools cmd prompt, download the Qt source.
Then type `configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010` and `nmake`

Answer (score 1):

Simply Add Kit for 64 bit target and build for that target.

[image]